Tetralogy order sequence novel series
I'm writing a novel series based on my life experiences. Not a memior. I'm starting on a time that is in the middle of my life story. My next book will be about a time prior to the story in my current book. The third book will go back further in my history, and the forth book will jump to a current part of my life. Can I do this? Or is this against rules for writing?

You can do this. It is not against any rules of writing.
Not all stories are told chronologically. There are stories that start with the ending and then narrate how that ending came to pass. There are stories that work backwards from the present like yours does. There are stories that "jump around" in time.
The chronological order of events is only one possible thread that a narrative can follow. Other stories follow an explanations (of an outcome, of a situation, of how a person become who he is), and the unfolding elements of that explanations can lie in non-consecutive parts of historic time. Yet other stories follow other connections between the elements of a story – relationships, factual arguments that the author wants to make, and so on.
Allow yourself to be guided by the internal logic of how your narrative unfolds.

Thank you. My mind says I am correct, but my inexperience warns me to know the truth before proceeding. I appreciate your feed back!
